# Save 3 lists to text seperated by commas

Tags: c#, list, foreach

I have three lists of ingredients, amounts and units. I need to save all three to a text file separated by commas. e.g. `[ingredient],[amount],[units]`. I'm currently using nested `foreach` loops but this way it saves every combination of them. How would I go about fixing this?

```
foreach (string q in ingredients)
{
    foreach (int w in newAmounts)
    {
        foreach (string r in units)
        {
            writer.Write(q + ",");
            writer.Write(w + ",");
            writer.Write(r + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Your code currently saves every combination of ingredients, amounts, and units to your file. How you do want it to preform? What is the relationship between the 3 lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all your lists have same count then you can use one for loop instead of three foreach:

```
for(int i=0; i<ingredients.Count;i++)
{
   writer.Write(ingredients[i] + ",");
   writer.Write(newAmounts[i] + ",");
   writer.Write(units[i] + "\n");
 }
```

Comment: Without a relationship between the 3 tables, I can't recommend using this.

Comment: This solution does solve your problem, but assumes that all three lists are of equal length.  Based on the quesiton that is true, but it is also fragile.

Answer (score 0):

```
  for (int i = 0; i < ingredients.Length; i++)
  {
    writer.Write(string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}\n", ingredients[i], newAmounts[i], units[i]);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is [`Enumerable.Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It takes two `IEnumerable`s and turns them into an `IEnumerable` of a new type. If the three collections match on index, the code looks like this:

```
var tuples = ingredients
    .Zip(newAmounts,
        (i, a) => new Tuple<string, string>(i, a))
    .Zip(units,
        (t, a) => new Tuple<string, string, string>(t.Item1, t.Item2));

foreach (var t in tuples)
{
    writer.Write(t.Item1 + ",");
    writer.Write(t.Item2 + ",");
    writer.Write(t.Item3 + "\n");
}
```

The code may look a little ugly, but you can make it better by adding a few `ZipToTuple` helper functions to do the heavy lifing.

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<T1, T2>> ZipToTuple<T1, T2>(
    this IEnumerable<T1> e1,
    IEnumerable<T2> e2)
{
    return e1.Zip(e2,
        (t1, t2) => new Tuple<T1, T2>(t1, t2));
}

public static IEnumerable<Tuple<T1, T2, T3>> ZipToTuple<T1, T2, T3>(
    this IEnumerable<T1> e1,
    IEnumerable<T2> e2,
    IEnumerable<T3> e3)
{
    return e1
        .ZipToTuple(e2)
        .Zip(e3,
            (t, t3) => new Tuple<T1, T2, T3>(t.Item1, t.Item2, t3));
}
```

Then the code becomes:

```
foreach (var t in ingredients.ZipToTuple(newAmounts, units))
{
    writer.Write(t.Item1 + ",");
    writer.Write(t.Item2 + ",");
    writer.Write(t.Item3 + "\n");
}
```

Comment: Good effort, but without a clear understanding of what the OP wants, it is hard to give a good answer.

Comment: Yep. Without more information, the only relationship I can assume between those lists is index order. However, index order relationships happen to be an intuitive pattern for new programmers (like those who don't yet fully understand the implications of inner loops) so I would wager that my assumption is correct.

Comment: You know, when I first looked at this, I thought the answer was "just make 3 separate foreach loops". Maybe I was being too simple or everyone else's is overkill.

Comment: Well, that wouldn't have worked because he specifically wanted a heterogeneous mix of ingredients, amounts, and units on each line, but many of the simpler answers on this thread are more than sufficient for this problem, as shown by the OP's acceptance of one of them.